# Ajax.ActionLink not showing alert onsuccess

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery

I have ajax.actionlink in my form:

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm("UpdateRecordingDetails", "Recording", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "frmRecordingEdit" }))
   {%>
       <%= Ajax.ActionLink("Event Notifications", "procesCallrecording", new { Id = ViewData["RecordingIDsEdit"] }, new AjaxOptions { OnSuccess = "alert('success message');" })%>
    <%            
   } 
%>
```

and controller action is like this:

```
public JsonResult procesCallrecording(int Id = 0 ) 
{
    return Json("success", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<%= Ajax.ActionLink("Event Notifications", "procesCallrecording", 
    new { Id = ViewData["RecordingIDsEdit"] }, 
    new AjaxOptions { 
        OnSuccess = "function() { alert('success message'); 
    }" })%>
```

And better way to do check [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10272733/ajax-actionlink-get-data-or-error-message-from-controller)

Comment: @aliRaza, It writes success on webpage instead of showing alert.

Answer (score 0):

I think the `OnSuccess` callback of Ajax.ActionLink expects a `javascript` function name to invoke when the event occurs.

```
      <%= Ajax.ActionLink("Event Notifications", "procesCallrecording", new { Id = ViewData["RecordingIDsEdit"] }, new AjaxOptions { OnSuccess = "success" })%>
```

And the javascript as you expect is an alert.

```
   <script>
  function success(){
         alert('success message');
    }
   </script>
```

This way you can try

Answer (score 0):

If this is an ASP.NET MVC 2 application make sure that you have included the `MicrosoftAjax.js` and `MicrosoftMvcAjax.js` scripts to your page:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<%= Url.Content("~/scripts/MicrosoftAjax.js") %>"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<%= Url.Content("~/scripts/MicrosoftMvcAjax.js") %>"></script>
```

In ASP.NET MVC 3 or later those are obsolete and should no longer be used. They are replaced by the `jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js` script.